# Has Thor fought with himself from a different timeline?

Tags: marvel, comics, thor-marvel

In Marvel comics, time travel exists, so it is possible for two versions of the same person from different timelines to meet. I would like to know if Thor ever fought another version of himself from a different timeline. If so, in which issue/s of the comics has this occurred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends what you mean by Thor fighting himself from a different timeline. Since you mentioned time travel in your question, it sounds to me like you're asking whether the real Thor Odinson ever fought an older or younger version of himself from the past or the future. And if that's what you meant, then I don't believe a fight like that has ever happened.

We did see the real Thor meet [an older version of himself](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-14412)), and later a younger version of himself as well, but they didn't fight one another, opting to team up instead.

[Thor: God of Thunder Vol 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_God_of_Thunder_Vol_1_5)

[image]

[Thor: God of Thunder Vol 1 #8](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_God_of_Thunder_Vol_1_8)

[image]

[Thor Vol 5 #14](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_5_14)

[image]

Apparently, the Russo brothers [planned to have a fight scene between the present and past Thor in Avengers: Endgame](https://www.cbr.com/avengers-endgame-thor-vs-thor-fight/), but they had a change of heart and decided not to go with that.

If you count Thor Odinson fighting other versions of himself from alternate universes (with no time travel involved), then there've been two instances that I'm aware of. In the first instance, the [Thor Odinson of Earth 616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-616)) (the Thor of the prime Marvel universe, who was known as Unworthy Thor at the time) fought the [Thor Odinson of Earth-1610](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-1610)) (AKA, Ultimate Thor).

[Thors Vol 1 #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thors_Vol_1_2)

[image]

And in the second instance (which Raj cited in his answer), Ultimate Thor fought the [Thor of Earth-16001](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-16001)) (AKA, Rune Thor). They had *two* fights, in fact, in consecutive issues, but the following image is from the first.

[Thors Vol 1 #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thors_Vol_1_3)

[image]

If you're willing to count Thor Odinson fighting other people who wielded his powers and used his name, then there've been several instances of that.

Thor vs. ['Thor' (Red Norvell)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Roger_Norvell_(Earth-616)) - [Thor Vol 1 #478](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_478)

[image]

Thor vs. ['Thor' (Eric Masterson)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Masterson_(Earth-616)) - [Thor Vol 1 #459](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_459)

[image]

Thor vs. ['Thor' (Jane Foster)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Foster_(Earth-616)) - [Thor Vol 4 #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_4_4)

[image]

Thor Odinson has also had multiple fights with [Beta Ray Bill](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill_(Earth-616)), who doesn't typically use his name, but does wield his powers.

[Thor Vol 1 #472](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_472)

[image]

If you're willing to count other people with Thor's powers fighting *each other*, then there've been at least a couple of instances of that as well.

'Thor' (Eric Masterson) vs. ['Thor' (Dargo Ktor)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dargo_Ktor_(Earth-8710)) - [Thor Vol 1 #439](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_439) (also cited in Raj's answer)

[image]

'Thor' (Jane Foster) vs. ['War Thor' (Volstagg)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Volstagg_(Earth-616)) - [Mighty Thor Vol 2 #23](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_2_23)

[image]

I'm fairly sure the last half-dozen examples weren't really the sort of thing you had in mind, but just in case I'm wrong about that, I decided to include them anyway.

Comment: Just checking, but do you have the right to publish these images under a Creative Commons license as you indicated when you used the 'add picture' form?

Comment: @DavidMulder those fall in the "fair use" category, as pretty much any picture on this site.

Comment: @Jenayah No they don't, as SE doesn't allow a fair use exception (see https://creativecommons.org/faq/#may-i-apply-a-cc-license-to-my-work-if-it-incorporates-material-used-under-fair-use-or-another-exception-or-limitation-to-copyright) and fair use doesn't allow you to publish something under a creative commons license. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327528/are-we-allowed-according-to-the-tos-to-exempt-a-part-of-our-post-from-the-cc-lic

Comment: @DavidMulder ah... Then I'm way in over my head in the legal stuff :) there was this previous discussion [here on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1849/98028), does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jenayah Yeah, that post is completely false. Note how it's from the early days (2012) and the user is deleted. And just so you know, I only called you out on it because of the number of images in your post as I know a lot of people aren't aware :)

Comment: @DavidMulder well this above isn't my post, but being in the habit of posting comics pictures as well it certainly applies to me, too. I'll read that Meta post when I have more time and see how I should change/adapt this habit

Answer (score 9):

**Yes.*** In Battleworld: [Thors #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thors_Vol_1_4), [Thunderer Thorlief](https://www.marvel.com/characters/thor-ultimate) was forced to battle [Rune Thor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-16001)) after the latter killed [Stormbreaker Ray](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill_(Earth-15513)).

If mortals possessing the power of Thor count as well, then there's at least one more example: In [Thor # 440](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/11768/thor_1966_440) Zarrko tricks [Dargo Ktor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dargo_Ktor_(Earth-8710)), the Thor of the future, in to fighting [Eric Masterson](https://www.marvel.com/characters/thunderstrike-eric-masterson) (when he was still Thor, before he became Thunderstrike).

Comment: Dargo Ktor and Eric Masterson were different people, rather than the same person from different timelines. Also, neither one was the real Thor; they were just humans wielding Thor's hammer and power, so I don't think that example counts.